# Swap rows or columns of a 2d array in O(1) time in c++

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, swap

My question is that how can you swap two rows or two columns of a 2D array in O(1) time?,I searched on internet and i found a function memcpy but i don't know how to use it.
for example

given a matrix:

```
1 2 3 
4 5 6 
7 8 9
```

if we swap row 1 and row 2

```
4 5 6
1 2 3
7 8 9
```

Comment: your teacher is asking you to swap row pointers.

Comment: If it's a 2D array, then you can't do the swap in O(1) (you have to copy each element from one row to another, so the runtime depends on the number of columns, which is not O(1) unless your array always has the same number of columns.). You could try an array of pointers instead where swapping two rows, however long, is only a matter of swapping two pointers.

Comment: can u please explain with a code

Comment: Being abole to swap both rows and columns in o(1) is a different question. this is not a duplicate.

Comment: memcpy won't be O(1). Whether this is possible depends on how the data structure is implemented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an indirect array on both rows and columns. In other words to access an element `i,j` you use

```
data[rowix[i]][colix[j]]
```

instead of plain

```
data[i][j]
```

This is still an O(1) for element access (albeit with a larger constant factor), but also allows you to swap both rows and columns in constant time (just swap the index arrays elements).

In C++

```
template<int ROWS, int COLS, typename T>
struct Mat2d {
    T data[ROWS][COLS];
    int colix[COLS], rowix[ROWS];
    Mat2d() {
        for (int i=0; i<ROWS; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<COLS; j++) {
                data[i][j] = T();
            }
        }
        for (int i=0; i<ROWS; i++) rowix[i] = i;
        for (int j=0; j<COLS; j++) colix[j] = j;
    }
    T& operator()(int i, int j) { return data[rowix[i]][colix[j]]; }
    T operator()(int i, int j) const { return data[rowix[i]][colix[j]]; }
    void swapRows(int i1, int i2) { std::swap(rowix[i1], rowix[i2]); }
    void swapCols(int j1, int j2) { std::swap(colix[j1], colix[j2]); }
};
```

Every problem in programming can be solved by adding an indirection level (except the problem of having too many indirection levels) ;-)

Comment: @NeilKirk: of course it can, but still it remains O(1) for element access, swapping rows and swapping columns.

Comment: His teacher will see right through him if he submits this answer :-D

Comment: WAY too complicated.  Teacher did not ask for a system that can swap rows AND COLUMNS arbitrarily.  Only asked for something that can swap ROWS in O(1).  Teacher is trying to make student think of representing a 2D array using a 1D array of pointers to 1D arrays.  Try solving this without using templates.  (cf. "Ragged Array" / "Jagged Array"...)